# Disable right-click to textboxes VB.net 2010

Tags: textbox, keypress, paste

I already use KeyPress event to avoid inputting of symbols or special characters (especially for query) but right click event is still functioning and be able to paste special characters and may cause a run-time error. Is there a way to prevent right-clicking on textboxes or can right-click but disable paste?

```
Private Sub txtLastName_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtLastName.KeyPress, txtFirstName.KeyPress, txtMiddleName.KeyPress

    If Not (Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8) Then
        Dim allowedChars As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.- ,"
        If Not allowedChars.Contains(e.KeyChar.ToString.ToLower) Then
            e.KeyChar = ChrW(0)
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

i found it.. just set the ShortcutsEnabled property of textbox to false.. :)